# How to read in file of keywords and hash on file of entries

Tags: python

Thank you all for your responses.  No, this isn't a homework assignment.  It was a real-world problem that I needed to solve for work.  I wanted to use it as a spring-board to learning python rather than tackling it on perl.  I will be more careful with submissions in the future.  I solved this problem with much googling.  First script.  Thanks again.

File A has a list of keywords (some lines in the file may have two keywords separated by a comma).  I need to use these keywords to search another file (File B) and extract the lines that match, after which I need to read one specific entry on that comma separated line.

The algorithm is simple enough but, as I'm trying to learn Python at the same time, I'm not sure how to proceed.  My initial start was to read File B into a list, but I'm wondering if a dictionary is better.

FILE A format:

```
STRING, NUM 1, NUM 2, NUM 3
```

FILE B format:

```
STRING A, STRING B
```

I want to search for STRING A in FILE A, the STRING B in FILE A, and extract NUM 1 from each and add them together.

Comment: In the example, I swapped FILE A and FILE B

Comment: I can tell writing this question was rushed, could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37008903/edit) your question with a more coherent example, I do not understand what your files actually look like or what you want as the end result.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen:  Thoughts on the edit now?  I did what I could.

Comment: Can you give us some more details on the structure of the file?  Is it the case that the strings in File B are all comma-separated?  Does each string followed by numbers in File A live on its own line?

Comment: Refer : [Python; reading file and finding desired text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809373/python-reading-file-and-finding-desired-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the contents of *File A* in a dictionary with *String* as key and numbers as values. Then iterate over *(String A, String B)* in *File B* and search for both the *Strings* in the dictionary. You can use Pandas alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, but I'll at least point you in the right direction.

For file A, you'll definitely want a dictionary. So, first step is to iterate over the lines of file A, and as you do so, add items to a dictionary where the key is STRING, and the value is perhaps a tuple of NUM1, NUM2, NUM3. You can use the split() function to convert the line from a string to a list of the 4 items. You'll probably also need to use int() to actually make the numbers into integer type. Now that you have this dictionary, iterate over the lines of file B, and lookup STRING A and STRING B (again using split() to separate the values), and add those two NUM1's together.